# Plot two y values picking up the right x values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two columns like this:

> [image] [image]

I want to plot 1 graph where

- x axis = union of all values in both rule_number columns,
- y axis = two series, one for values from Values1, other for values in Values2.

If there's no y value for an X eg. x= 5-0-15 doesn't exist in Values1, show that as zero on the graph.

I want the x data ticks to show exactly the way they are eg. 18-0-1, 7-3-1, so I'm treating them as text, not numbers but that's confusing all the plots I've tried bar/scatter.

How do I do this?

Comment: Before you do anything else, format your rule_number columns as text. You will find that some of your labels have been interpreted as dates, so you need to type the actual labels.

Answer (score 0):

To treat all `x` values as text you should precede each of them by an apostrophe.
Depending on your version of Excel you can create a union of both `x` columns by a formula:

```
=UNIQUE(VSTACK(A2:A15,C2:C15))
```

(new versions) or using `Remove duplicates` to a stacked column of all `x` values.
To create lists of `y` values `Values1` and `Values2` you can use either

```
=XLOOKUP($F$2:$F$17,$A$2:$A$15,$B$2:$B$15,0)
```

or

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP($F$2:$F$17,$A$2:$B$15,2,FALSE),0)
```

Then simply plot a linear or column chart.
[image: chart data]

[image: data ploy]